# Laravel routing with or without parameter in a group

Tags: laravel, routes

For my application I am trying to create a few routes entries.
One entry to initialise the application and another for AJAX requests.

So my application should hit the `initialise` function if I type `https.test.com/app/drive` but also if I want to type some additional parameters at the end something like this: `https:test.com/app/drive/specificTabA` or `https:test.com/app/drive/specificTabB`

The problem is that when ever I type `https.test.com/drive/specificTabNameA` this clashes with the `fetchData` get route used by my AJAX call.

How can I access the initialise function when hitting this URl `https.test.com/app/drive` or also hitting something like this: `https:test.com/app/drive/specificTabA` or `https:test.com/app/drive/specificTabB`?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'drive'], function () {
    Route::get('', 'CustomController@initialise');
    Route::get('fetchData', 'CustomController@fetchData');
});
```

Comment: Put this group before `https.test.com/drive/{specificTabNameA}` route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some tests, and came with the following conclusion/solution:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'drive'], function () {
    Route::get('fetchData', 'CustomController@fetchData');
    Route::get('{param?}', 'CustomController@initialise');
});
```

CustomerController:

```
function initialise($param = null) 
{
    ...
}
```

Note that by changing the order of the routes you will actually load the correct route.

When you visit `/drive/fetchData` it will load `fetchData` route

When you visit `/drive/` it will load `initialise` route without arguments

When you visit `/drive/xyz` it will load `initialise` route with `$param` being `xyz`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It was the order that mattered and I was not aware, so now everything is working how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

My friend I want to get your attention to Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters especially this one Route Parameters. You can tell router that this route can have parameter but also can not have it. Look at this example

```
Route::get('/{specific?}')
```

Now you can get this specific parameter in your Controller function after request

```
public function initialize (Request $request, $specific = null)
```

Set it default to null as this param can both be past and not, so it should have some default value. 
Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'drive'], function () {
    Route::get('fetchData', 'CustomController@fetchData');

    Route::get('{path?}', 'CustomController@initialise')->where(['path' => '.*']);
});
```

This will allow the following path:

`/drive` => `initialise`

`/drive/1` => `initalize`

`/drive/1/2/3` => `initalize`

`/drive/fetchData` => `fetchData`

Adding `->where(['path' => '.*'])` will route any path to `initalize`, e.g. `/1`, `/1/2`, `/1/2/3`.

If you only want to allow the path to be one level deep you can remove the where:

```
Route::get('{path?}', 'CustomController@initialise');
```